# How to measure power usage effectiveness (PUE)

Tags: datacenter, electrical-power

As part of a sustainability project I have been requested to measure the PUE of our server room. We have gross power usage figures from the UPS (and seperate supply meters) but nothing else. How in a practical way should I go about getting the rest of the data I need?

Comment: Do you mean efficiency?

Comment: Some of the info here may help out http://serverfault.com/questions/26039/how-do-i-calculate-cooling-cost-per-server

Comment: As a first step, and generic rule of thumb, older servers do not support dynamic power reduction and thus burn more electricity than newer (and usually more powerful) servers. Also consolidation through virtualization generally reduces your server electric bill by 2x for small installations and 6 to 8x for larger server rooms.

Comment: Thanks for the info FarSeeker, Kara and Chris. To clarify PUE is the ratio between the total power consumed by the server room / data centre and the power actually used by the servers. It is a measure of datacentre power efficiency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To measure the actual power usage of a server, get an electric meter like the [Kill-A-Watt P4320](http://www.google.com/search?q=kill-a-watt+p4320); it costs about $60 and will measure the power usage of most typical servers (monster servers and 48v need not apply).

Also, Jeff's blog article ["Why Estimate when you can Measure"](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/08/why-estimate-when-you-can-measure.html) has some good information.

Comment: Developing from Chris S's answer, I have found you can buy PDUs with inbuilt watt meters that either display on the PDU or the information can be sent to a server for consolidation

Answer (score 1):

There is some great information about what Power Usage Effectiveness (PUE) is, how to practically measure it, and even a simple calculator found [here](http://www.42u.com/measurement/pue-dcie.htm).